# How to know current file in large Move operation?

Tags: nautilus

I have large move operation running. I am doing it through the GUI. Is there a way to know what's the current file being moved?

Comment: Moving within the same partition should be pretty fast, I guess you're either moving to another partition or copying, correct?

Comment: Do you want the GUI to show you which file it is operating on?  Or do you want to write a program to figure it out?

Comment: @kos I am moving through the network.

Comment: @wallyk. Whatever solution works. Problem is the copy dialog is already running and I want to figure out what it is copying/moving right now (without restarting the copy!)

Comment: Not that I know. Nautilus is somehow a very basic file manager. I can advise to use krusader. It is the closest equivalent to the mighty total commander. Hope it helps.

Comment: to answers your last comment: perhaps you can do from a terminal an ls -ltr in the destination folder and see which is the latest file that is chaining in size.

Comment: @AndreaBorga What if it is a directory?

Comment: @becko:  "directories" *per se* are not actually copied.  Only their contents.

Comment: in fact a "directory" is a file.:) this is one of the basic concepts of linux systems... well something that is more flashed out with respect to other OS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the process id (pid) of the copy command.
2. List the files at `/proc/`(pid)`/fd`

For example, doing this for an editing session shows:

```
$ ll /proc/7496/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 wally wally 64 Jul  9 21:02 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 wally wally 64 Jul  9 21:02 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 wally wally 64 Jul  8 23:44 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 wally wally 64 Jul  9 21:02 4 -> /home/wally/.bashrc.swp
```